# How to copy huge file(200-500GB) everyday from Teradata server to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, flume

I have teradata files on SERVER A and I need to copy to Server B into HDFS. what options do i have?
distcp is ruled because Teradata is not on HDFS
scp is not feasible for huge files
Flume and Kafka are meant for Streaming and not for file movement. Even if i use Flume using Spool_dir, it will be an overkill.

Only option I can think of is NiFi. Does anyone has any suggestions on how can i utilize Nifi?
or if someone has already gone through these kind of scenarios, what was the approach followed?

Comment: Nifi uses the file system to store intermediate data between processors. If it's ok - you can use nifi.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "to store intermediate data between processors". can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't specifically worked with Teradata dataflow in NiFi but having worked with other SQL sources on NiFi, I believe it is possible & pretty straight-forward to develop dataflow that ingests data from Teradata to HDFS.

For starters you can do a quick check with `ExecuteSQL` processor available in NiFi. The SQL related processors take one `DBCPConnectionPool` property which is a NiFi controller service which should be configured with the JDBC URL of your Teradata server and the driver path and driver class name. Once you validate the connection is fine, you can take a look at [`GenerateTableFetch`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html)/ [`QueryDatabaseTable`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html)

Hortonworks has an article which talks about configuring `DBCPConnectionPool` with a Teradata server : https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/45427/using-teradata-jdbc-connector-in-nifi.html

Comment: Thanks Siva. It will be helpful. I will keep everyone posted once I get exact requirement and the progress.